# Read and store multiple NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, nsarray, plist

can I store data for multiple NSMutableArrays in Objective C to a single plist file? If so how do I write this to the file and how do I read it? or would i need a separate file for each array I want to store?

I typically do this to read, but with only one array:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: you have to read more about the serializable objects first, and the serialization itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either save an array or a dictionary that contains the two arrays that you want to save.

```
NSArray *bothArrays = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSAssert(!bothArrays || bothArrays.count == 2, @"Expecting the array to be nil or to contain 2 items");
NSArray *first  = [bothArrays firstObject];
NSArray *second = [bothArrays lastObject];
```

Comment: This worked great. to clarify I created an Array of Arrays to write to the plist and then used the code above to read it out